# Windows: fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, windows, cygwin

Для запуска Linux программы в Windows использую cygwin
Но запускаемая программа использует

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
```

При компиляции в g++ выдаётся ошибка

```
"fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory"
```

Какой пакет нужно установить в cygwin, чтобы скомпилировать программу в операционной системе Windows?

Компилируемая Linux программа активно использует API epoll.

Comment: А вы компилируете из под Windows?

Comment: никакой. нужно поставить либо линукс, либо виртуалбок/аналоги и в нем линукс. Windows не поддерживает epoll.

Comment: По-моему ошибка компиляции "не хватает файла А" (No such file) говорит о том что нужно достать и положить файл А а именно epoll.h в папку includes\sys. Если функционал не используется удалите его из include или создайте пустой. Скачайте библиотеку epoll.h с нета.

Comment: epool это подсистема linux , всёравно что подложить файл windows.h при сборке и надеяться что виндовая программа будет работать под linux'ом , epoll.h можно найти наверное в любых исходниках linux систем

Comment: Вообще-то есть попытка сэмулировать epoll для cygwin, но насколько она удачная, и насколько такой подход вообще оправдан - не уверен: https://github.com/fd00/cygepoll

Comment: Ваша программа не кроссплатформенная. Увы. Перепишите её или попросите автора обеспечить кроссплатформенность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из комментариев:

---

Ваша программа не кроссплатформенная. Увы. Перепишите её или попросите автора обеспечить кроссплатформенность.

---

нужно поставить либо линукс, либо виртуалбок/аналоги и в нем линукс. Windows не поддерживает epoll.

---

epool это подсистема linux , всёравно что подложить файл windows.h при сборке и надеяться что виндовая программа будет работать под linux'ом , epoll.h можно найти наверное в любых исходниках linux систем

---

Вообще-то есть попытка сэмулировать epoll для cygwin, но насколько она удачная, и насколько такой подход вообще оправдан - не уверен: https://github.com/fd00/cygepoll